# (Geany) Typing normally caused the error "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, geany

Note: I know that questions with this error already exist. However, I believe that this question is not a duplicate of any of the questions I have already seen, as it's... pretty weird.

I was just using Geany 1.37 to build a blank program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
// This line is referred to as "line 8" below

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The above program, when I hit the "Build" button, compiled normally. However, I then typed `using namespace abc = std;` on line 8, and tried building again. When I hit the "Build" button at the top of the interface, however, I suddenly got the error message

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

(I know that `using namespace abc = std` would have caused a compilation error; I was curious as to what the compilation error would say exactly).

Now, I seem unable to build my program at all. My build commands have not changed at all, so I've come to the conclusion that I might've accidentally hit a weird keyboard shortcut that triggered this problem while typing `using namespace abc;`. Can somebody please tell me if a keyboard shortcut has been known to cause this issue, and what that keyboard shortcut would be?

Comment: I don't know Geany, but the symptom sounds like you managed to close your project while leaving the file open. Is there a keyboard shortcut for closing your project?

Comment: The make error has nothing to do with any C++ code. For whatever reason your Makefile got deleted. Unfortunately, the problem with most IDEs is that if something goes wrong it's very hard to figure out what's broken and how to fix a complicated contraption whose real mechanics are hidden behind pretty buttons and colorful dialogs. Learning how to write a Makefile yourself, and invoke the compiler and the linker the old fashioned way means that nothing is a hidden secret, and when something breaks you know where to look to fix it. You should consider learning how to use `make`.

Comment: Hmm, well I just rebooted my computer, and the problem has seemingly... disappeared. I'm sorry for wasting your time: I should have rebooted and tested the error before posting a question about it.

Overall, I think JaMiT's comment sounds reasonable to me (I mashed a lot of keys and probably did manage to close my file). I'll also definitely start taking a look into Makefile, @Sam Varshavchik. Thanks for commenting so quickly on my question.

Comment: No need to apologize. I just hate to see people frustrated when fragile IDEs go haywire on them, and suddenly they have no idea what to do next. It's broken, and the breakage is buried somewhere where nobody even knows. There's a lot to say about using simple, unsophisticated text-only build toolchains, where the only thing anyone needs is a plain text editor that can be used to fix everything. One of the popular IDEs is just a glorified Makefile editor, and when it goes bonkers, and you simply open the Makefile in a text editor, find the problem and fix it, people stare at you.